# iPad/iPhone CoreMidi - Mackie Control Emulation (stop, play buttons)

Tags: controls, logic, midi, coremidi

I faced with very hard problem.

My task is to emulate Mackie Control Pro - Stop and Play buttons.

I know that Note93 (A5) - it is stop encoder. Note 94 (A5#) this is Play encoder.
Basically I'm sending Note On 93, 127 velocity then Note Off 93, 0 velocity, and Logic receive stop message, but after this he just went crazy, he sending many midi messages (note on,off 93) in loop, when I click play, it went more crazy. ((((

That how I'm sending message to Network Session:

Touch Down

```
 UInt8 midiData[]  = { 0x90, 93, 127};
        [midi sendBytes:midiData size:sizeof(midiData)];
```

Touch Up

```
UInt8 midiData[]  = { 0x80, 93, 0};
        [midi sendBytes:midiData size:sizeof(midiData)];
```

The most interesting that when I play not A5, A5# in ThumbJam app (for iPad/iPhone), it works good. The same in eyoControl app, it works. But when I play A5, A5# key in TouchOSC or TB MIDI Stuff or Midi Designer, etc - then Logic went again to loop. And in the Midi Monitor messages the same in all applications. CRAZY... I can't understand this ((

What the difference, all applications connected and working seems via CoreMidi.
p.s. with Ableton Live, Reason everething ok. Buttons works.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution. Instead of sending Note Off, application should send note on but with zero velocity.

instead {0x80, keynumber, 0} use {0x90, keynumber, 0}

Comment: Yes, the note off messages are done can vary from device to device.  It is my understanding that zero-velocity note on is more compatible, but I don't know if there is data to back that claim up.  At a minimum, using zero-velocity allows you to keep running status for subsequent note messages, saving bandwidth.